# Echo Joomla K2 Item Title in Main Template Using PHP

Tags: joomla, title, joomla-k2

I'm trying to simply echo the title of the current k2 item I'm viewing, but the echo will not occur within the K2 template, it should show in my MAIN site template.

I tried this:

```
<?php echo $this->title; ?>
```

But that displays the FULL site title including my company name because I have it set that way in the main Joomla configuration.

I don't want the full site title that is generated for the 'title' tag in the head of the website; I just want to generate the name of the specific item I am currently viewing.  This is probably pretty easy, but my PHP knowledge is limited.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is pretty old. However if you are still looking for a solution. This is not very elegant but will do what you want.

Firstly, just in case you weren't aware, you can get the article id from anywhere in by doing a `JRequest:getVar('id')` which will use a GET request to get the id from the URL.

```
$id = JRequest::getVar('id'); 
$id = explode(':',$id);
echo $id[0];
```

The reason I am exploding it is because in my site I am using aliases which if you are and you echo $id without you will see its in the form `id:alias`.

Using this method, you could query the database to get the `name` associated with that id in the `k2_items` table. You could create a function to do that which is else where in the templates folder then just assign it to a variable which you echo in the template. That keeps your template clean but gives you what you want.

Like I say, not a quick elegant solution but will work.